# Gmap excpetion due to make setup file using Wix

Tags: c#, google-maps, wix, installation

I want to make setup file form my C# application, this app use external Library which is "Gmap" lib.
So the form of the C# App look like following:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            Map.Top = 2;
            Map.Left = 2;
            Map.Width = 500;
            Map.Height = 1000;
            try
            {
                System.Net.IPHostEntry q = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("www.google.com");
            }
            catch
            {
                Map.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
            }
            Map.MapProvider = GMapProviders.BingSatelliteMap;
            Map.Position = new PointLatLng(32.528361, 35.924263); //new PointLatLng(25.470709, 55.52634);//PointLatLng(32.528361, 35.924263);// Map.Position = new PointLatLng(32.49159, 35.994);
            Map.CacheLocation = Application.StartupPath;
            Map.MinZoom = 1;
            Map.MaxZoom = 20;
            Map.Zoom = 16;
            Map.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
        }catch(Exception e)
        { MessageBox.Show(e.ToString()); }
    }
```

when I run this App, it successfully show the map and there was no problem at all.

But when I try to convert it to be as setup file, I use the Wix toolset my .wsx as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Last">
                <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
                 <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="{BA6619DF-FA4C-4537-BD61-684BB2E0457F}">
         <File Source="$(var.d.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
                 </Component>

      <Component Id="ProductComponent2" Guid="{04116569-43D0-4433-A158-E24938CCE88A}">
        <File Source="..\d\bin\Debug\GMap.NET.Core.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id="ProductComponent3" Guid="{BCE640B2-8E99-4B02-B28C-9DA9E8841F7C}">
        <File Source="..\d\bin\Debug\GMap.NET.WindowsForms.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>

    </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Last" Level="1">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this ComponentRef element and the Component above in order to add resources to this installer. -->
         <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent2" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent3" />
  <!-- Note: The following ComponentGroupRef is required to pull in generated authoring from project references. -->
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated" />
    </Feature>
</Product>
```

when I install the setup file, and then go to the program file to run the .exe of the APP, I have this exception:

[image]

How can I use these external lib in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you remove `Map.CacheLocation = Application.StartupPath;` and use the default location. The cache location must be in a writable folder for the users.

Programs, when run by users, do not write to locations where administrators have installed program files. Also, programs don't normally share data between users without making it clear to the users. If you do want to share the cache, you can use a common location such as [CommonApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) 
  + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "GMap.NET" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
```